# I want to send an email after Suite is executed in selenium TestNG java?

Tags: java, selenium, email, testng

I have a testSuite in which I run ForgotPasswordTest.java class. At the end of suite execution, I want to send an email of the emailable report generated using AfterSuite method. How do I do it?

Here is my suite:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Suite" parallel="false" verbose="2">
  <listeners>
    <listener class-name="utility.ScreenshotOnFailure" />
    <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter" />
  </listeners> <test name="Run on Chrome">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
    <parameter name="grid" value="yes"></parameter>
    <parameter name="baseURL" value="https://dev.miride.com/"/>
    <classes>
      <!-- <class name="test.LoginPageTest"/> -->
      <!-- <class name="test.SignUpPageTest"/> -->
      <class name="test.ForgotPasswordTest"/>
     <!--  <class name="test.miAccountPageTest"/> -->
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

My ForgotPasswordTest.java class is as follows:

```
package test;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import core.OpenAndCloseBrowser;
import dataProvider.DataProviderForForgotPasswordPage;
import email.emailReport;
import pages.ForgotPasswordPage;
import pages.HomePage;
import pages.LoginPage;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
public class ForgotPasswordTest extends OpenAndCloseBrowser{

    //TC#1 - Test case to request for new password reset link
    @Test(dataProviderClass=DataProviderForForgotPasswordPage.class,dataProvider="ForgotPassword_TC1")
    public void ForgotPassword_TC1(String emailaddress) throws Exception{
    HomePage homePage = new HomePage(getDriver());
    LoginPage loginPage = homePage.clickLoginLink();
    ForgotPasswordPage fppage = loginPage.clickForgotPasswordLink();
    fppage.enterEmailAddress(emailaddress);
    fppage.clickResetPasswordBtn();
    }

    //TC#2 - Test case to verify validation message in case of clearing email address field
    @Test(dataProviderClass=DataProviderForForgotPasswordPage.class,dataProvider="ForgotPassword_TC2")
    public void ForgotPassword_TC2(String emailaddress, String validation) throws Exception{
    HomePage homePage = new HomePage(getDriver());
    LoginPage loginPage = homePage.clickLoginLink();
    ForgotPasswordPage fppage = loginPage.clickForgotPasswordLink();
    fppage.enterEmailAddress(emailaddress);
    fppage.clear_EmailAddress(emailaddress);
    fppage.verify_ValidationMessage(validation);
    }

    //TC#3 - Test case to verify validation message in case of unregistered email address
    @Test(dataProviderClass=DataProviderForForgotPasswordPage.class,dataProvider="ForgotPassword_TC3")
    public void ForgotPassword_TC3(String emailaddress, String validation) throws Exception{
    HomePage homePage = new HomePage(getDriver());
    LoginPage loginPage = homePage.clickLoginLink();
    ForgotPasswordPage fppage = loginPage.clickForgotPasswordLink();
    fppage.enterEmailAddress(emailaddress);
    fppage.clickResetPasswordBtn();
    fppage.verify_ValidationMessage(validation);
    }

    //TC#4 - Test case to verify validation message in case of invalid email address
    @Test(dataProviderClass=DataProviderForForgotPasswordPage.class,dataProvider="ForgotPassword_TC4")
    public void ForgotPassword_TC4(String emailaddress, String validation) throws Exception{
    HomePage homePage = new HomePage(getDriver());
    LoginPage loginPage = homePage.clickLoginLink();
    ForgotPasswordPage fppage = loginPage.clickForgotPasswordLink();
    fppage.enterEmailAddress(emailaddress);
    fppage.verify_ValidationMessage(validation);
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void sendMail(){
        emailReport.execute();
    }
}
```

Also, my Email Report.java is as follows:

```
package email;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;

public class emailReport {


public static void execute() {

    // Create object of Property file
    Properties props = new Properties();

    // this will set host of server- you can change based on your requirement 
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");

    // set the port of socket factory 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");

    // set socket factory
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

    // set the authentication to true
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    // set the port of SMTP server
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    // This will handle the complete authentication
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,

            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

                return new PasswordAuthentication("radhikarj94@gmail.com", "xyz");

                }

            });

    try {

        // Create object of MimeMessage class
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

        // Set the from address
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("radhikarj94@gmail.com"));

        // Set the recipient address
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("radhikarj94@gmail.com"));

                    // Add the subject link
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");

        // Create object to add multimedia type content
        BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();

        // Set the body of email
        messageBodyPart1.setText("This is message body");

        // Create another object to add another content
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();

        // Mention the file which you want to send
        String filename = "./test-output/Suite/emailable-report.html";

        //String filename = System.getProperty("emailable-report.html") + "./test-output/Suite/emailable-report.html";//"./test-output/Suite/emailable-report.html";
     /* \\test-output\\emailable-report.html*/
        // Create data source and pass the filename
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);

        // set the handler
        messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));

        // set the file
        messageBodyPart2.setFileName(filename);

        // Create object of MimeMultipart class
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        // add body part 1
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);

        // add body part 2
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);

        // set the content
        message.setContent(multipart);

        // finally send the email
        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("=====Email Sent=====");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        System.out.println("=====Email failed=====");
        throw new RuntimeException(e);

    }

}

}
```

Sorry for the long code.
At the end, the console shows:

```
Suite
Total tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
```

Is there any thing i can do to correct my code?

Comment: Since you have one configuration method fail, I guess it is the one that you want to send out the email. You can try check more detail logs, so far, the output you attached doesn't say that much.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in TestNG report viz., `emailable-report.html` is generated by a reporting listener in TestNG.

By default, TestNG executes the reporting phase (i.e., invokes the `org.testng.IReporter#generateReport` method of the `org.testng.IReporter` interface implementation, only after all suites have run to completion.

A method annotated with `@AfterSuite` is executed before a suite runs to completion which means, it gets executed before the `emailable-report.html` is even generated.

That perhaps is why you are seeing a configuration failure i.e., a failure in your `@AfterSuite` annotated method.

To fix your problem, you should be creating a new reporter which implements `org.testng.IExecutionListener` the interface and within its `org.testng.IExecutionListener#onExecutionFinish` make a call to `emailReport.execute();`

That should help you get done what you are looking for.